# Sequelize findOrCreate not excluding attributes defined in the exclude array

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

Following is the code:

```
Accounts.findOrCreate({
    where: {
        userName: request.payload.userName
    },
    attributes: { exclude: ['password','sessionToken'] },
    defaults: request.payload
}).spread(function (account, created) {

    if (created) {
        var account = account.get({
            plain: true
        });

        console.log(account);   // has the password and sessionToken fields

        return reply(account).code(201);
    } else {
        return reply("user name already exists").code(422);
    }

});
```

I noticed that sequelize first fires a select query in which the password field is not present, then it fires an insert statement in which the password field is present, and that needs to be there.

I would just like the password and sessionToken not be present in the resulting account object. I could of course delete those properties from the object but I am looking for a more straightforward way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you need to delete those fields manually. According to the source code, `findOrCreate` method first fires the `findOne` function and then it goes with `create` if instance was not found. The `create` method does not accept `attributes` parameter. In such a case all fields will be returned.

Good solution would be to create instance method in the `Accounts` model in order to return an instance with only the desired attributes.

```
{
    instanceMethods: {
        toJson: function() {
            let account = {
                id: this.get('id'),
                userName: this.get('userName')
                // and other fields you want to include
            };

            return account;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could simply use the `toJson` method when returning raw representation of object:

```
Accounts.findOrCreate({ where: { userName: 'username' } }).spread((account, created) => {
    return account ? account.toJson() : null;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by piotrbienias you can follow his way otherwise just delete the unwanted elements like this:

```
Accounts.findOrCreate({
    where: {
        userName: request.payload.userName
    },
    defaults: request.payload
}).spread(function (account, created) {

    if (created) {
        var account = account.get({
            plain: true
        });
        delete account.password;
        delete account.sessionToken;
        console.log(account);   // now you don't have the password and sessionToken fields

        return reply(account).code(201);
    } else {
        return reply("user name already exists").code(422);
    }

});
```

Comment: you have to do: delete account.dataValues.password;